# Querying two tables as group/summary

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new with SQL syntax.

Here I have two tables:

```
table_income
             +------+-------+-------+
             |date  |Paper  |Plastic|
             +------+-------+-------+
             |01-01 | $4    | $9    |
             |01-02 | $7    | $10   |
             |01-02 | $9    | $0    |
             |01-03 | $1    | $2    |
             
             Total    $21      $ 21
             Total Income $42
```

And the following table:

```
table_spend
             +------+-------+-------+
             |date  | Bag   |Hat    |
             +------+-------+-------+
             |01-01 | $1     | $5     |
             |01-02 | $9     | $10    |
             |01-02 | $5     | $0     |
             |01-03 | $2     | $2     |
             
             Total    $17       $17
             Total Spend 34
```

The result I am looking for is :

```
                   Income       ||      Spend   
            Paper       | $ 21  || Bag  | $ 17    |
            Plastic     | $ 21  || Hat  | $ 17    |
            ---------------------------------------
            Balance $ 8
```

Above will be layout in html.

SQL is as follow, but I am stuck in what to do.

```
 Select sum(table_income.paper), sum (table_income.plastic)
                from table_income 
                union select sum(table_spend.bag),sum(table_spend.hat)
                from table_spend
```

Comment: I would firstly re-evaluate your table schema and consider *normalising* your data - your columns should be *rows*. What happens as your data grows and you have 5, 10, 100+ items?

Comment: I am sorry I dont get you.The column is the field name, right? and the row is the data.

Comment: The comment from @stu is (in my opinion ) something like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0170c42908990c0069e0539deffcd74  This also solve the naming of a column with a reserved word (`date`) ,which you should not do (generally speaking)

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Luuk

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Is the problem that the results from the query aren't what's desired, or how to markup the results as HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things

1. `sum (...)` is not known, there should not be a space after the function name, change it to `sum(...)`.
2. you might need to add aliasses to you columns, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0866f2eba2486b2ee8c3d88091a8fc18), the names in you result will be taken from the first query in the union, that's why you will not see `Column3` and/or `Column4`.  But that will not solve the fact that you have one column with `Paper` and `Bag` values. (and `Plastic` and `Hat`)

```
Select 
   sum(table_income.paper) as Column1, 
   sum(table_income.plastic) as Column2
from table_income 

union 
select 
   sum(table_spend.bag) as Column3,
   sum(table_spend.hat) as Column4
from table_spend
```

EDIT: To get all four columns, you can do:

```
select 
   x.Column1,
   x.Column2,
   y.Column3,
   y.Column4
FROM
(Select 
   sum(table_income.paper) as Column1, 
   sum(table_income.plastic) as Column2
from table_income) x
cross join (
   select 
      sum(table_spend.bag) as Column3,
      sum(table_spend.hat) as Column4
   from table_spend
   ) y
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93e2e137062edc863c3050bad59611c2)

Comment: Is it possible to transpose it? the columns become rows?